# ¿Cómo llamar un metodo de la clase hijo en la clase padre?

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, herencia

estoy intentando hacer una agenda con GUI en netbeans, sin embargo quiero separar en los métodos toda la programación como tal guardandolos en una subclase del mismo formulario.

Sin embargo cuando mando a llamar el método de la subclase me manda un NPE, no sé si alguien me pueda ayudar les dejo unas imágenes:

Aquí solo mando a llamar a la clase hija:

[image: Casteo a la clase hija:]

Y en ésta parte es donde quiero que al dar click me mande a llamar el metodo "prueba" que se encuenta en la clase hija.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la clase hija donde está el metodo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, intento hacer el GUI un poco más orientado a objetos pero estos errores son los que me marcan: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debe instanciar antes de acceder al método prueba , tal cuál como está su línea comentada en el constructor de agenda

Comment: si instancio me marca el siguiente error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:507)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
 at Agenda.<init>(Agenda.java:20)
 at Metodos.<init>(Metodos.java:16)
 at Agenda.<init>(Agenda.java:21)
 at Metodos.<init>(Metodos.java:16)

Comment: Por favor , añadir el código en formato texto en lugar de imágenes  incluyendo los mensajes de error , ahora una pregunta puntual, ¿Cuál es la intención de extender de una clase que a su vez extiende de `JFrame`?  si no extiende su clase `Metodos` de Agenda seguro no tendrá ese error.

Comment: Si, una disculpa, pensé que con imágenes sería un poco más claro, pero lo que pasa es que como lo dije, es un formulario la clase principal de "Agenda" y si no hago el extends, tendré que pasar absolutamente todos los valores de Agenda a la clase Métodos, por lo que, ahi solo paso un método que imprime algo en consola, pero al final de cuentas lo que ocupo son los elementos de Frame que tengo como textfields.

Comment: Si, y me sale el siguiente error: 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:507)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)

Comment: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` es el resultado de recursión infinita, lo que cuál sucede en tu clase `Metodos`. Tratas de instanciar un nuevo `Metodos`, llamando a su vez la clase Agenda (puesto que está `extendida`), es decir, que pasará por esa instancia infinidad de veces dando como resultado un `java.lang.StackOverflowError `

Comment: Ohh, muchas gracias @C.Rodriguez, entonces hay alguna forma de "instanciarlo" para llamar el método?

Comment: Como indica @Dev.Joel, no extiendas de la clase `Agenda`, sino que pásale la referencia a la clase `Metodos`

Comment: Vale, lo voy a probar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Saludos, Kris.

`java.lang.StackOverflowError` es el resultado de recursión infinita, lo que cuál sucede en tu clase `Metodos`. Tratas de instanciar un nuevo `Metodos`, llamando a su vez la clase `Agenda` (puesto que está extendida), es decir, que pasará por esa instancia infinidad de veces dando como resultado un `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Para evitarlo, no extiendas `Agenda` en la clase `Metodos`, sino que pásale una referencia.

Puedes intentar realizar algo como esto:

```
public class Metodos {

    private final Agenda agenda;

    public Metodos(Agenda agenda) {
        this.agenda = agenda;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Agenda extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Declaración de tus variables...
    private Metodos metodos;

    public Agenda() {
        // Instancias otras variables...

        metodos = new Metodos(this);
    }

    // Declaración de más métodos...
}
```

De esta forma, podrías utilizar todos los métodos o variables de la clase `Agenda` según lo requieras en la clase `Metodos`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @C. Rodriguez  lo eh probado tal cual y me sirvió, claro que  para todas las variables tengo que agregarle el "agenda.[nombredel item]" pero muchas gracias.